# Explanation on access an object property that does not exist on an DOM element

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I am a beginner on JavaScript, looking for a explanation on accessing to an object property that does not exist on an DOM element.

I am working on a todo apps. Below is my current code but it is not completed.
There's an empty `todosArray`, then `todoObj` with two properties (`todo`, `completed`) will be added to the array when users add an item.

Later in the code where item can be removed or crossed out if users clicked on the item. In this click `addEventListener`, a variable `clickedEl` is created in the `else if` statement and it accessed/copied(?) the `completed` property from the `todosArray`. This is where I do not understand.

How is the `clickedEl` has access to the `completed` property? What is actually happening here?

```
// Variables 
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const formInput = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
const todosArray = [];

// Add item 
function addTodo(item) {
    const todoObj = {
        todo: item,
        completed: false
    };

    todosArray.push(todoObj);
    
    // Save to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('todosArray', JSON.stringify(todosArray));
    
    formInput.value = '';
};

// Add task to todo list
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (formInput.value === '') {
        alert('Please add a task.');
    }
    else {
        const newLi = document.createElement('li');
        newLi.innerHTML = formInput.value;
        ul.append(newLi);
        const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
        newLi.append(removeBtn);
        removeBtn.innerHTML = 'Remove';

        addTodo(formInput.value);
    };
});

// Remove/complete list item
ul.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.textContent === 'Remove') {
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
    }
    else if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {

        const clickedEl = e.target //li
        //console.log('clickedEl: ', clickedEl)
        if (clickedEl.completed === true) {
            clickedEl.style.textDecoration = 'none';
        }
        else {
            
            clickedEl.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
            clickedEl.completed = true;
        }
    }
});

// Retrieve from localStorage
if (localStorage.getItem('todosArray')) {
    const todosList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todosArray'));

    for (let i = 0; i < todosList.length; i++){
        const newLi = document.createElement('li');
        newLi.textContent = todosList[i].todo;
        ul.append(newLi);
        const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
        newLi.append(removeBtn);
        removeBtn.textContent = 'Remove';

        console.log(todosList[i]);
    }
}
```

I talked to a mentor but I was not able to understand his explanation. Also, googled quit a bit, but most results are related to property accessors.

Comment: `clickedEl.completed` has no relation to the `completed` property in `todosList`.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that does anything to `todosList` when you click on the item.

Answer (score 0):

DOM elements are not the same as plain JavaScript objects, meaning they don't have all the properties and methods that regular JavaScript objects have.

When you access e.target, you're getting a reference to the DOM element that triggered the event. It is a plain HTML element, does not have properties like completed.

```
else if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    const clickedEl = e.target; // This is a reference to the <li> element
    if (clickedEl.completed === true) { // Trying to access completed property
        clickedEl.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    } else {
        clickedEl.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
        clickedEl.completed = true; // Assigning a new property completed to the DOM element
    }
}
```

In this part, clickedEl refers to the list element that was clicked. There is no completed property defined on a regular DOM element. In JavaScript, you can dynamically add properties to objects, and this is what's happening below.

```
clickedEl.completed = true;
```

You're adding a new property completed to the list (li) element. This is why clickedEl.completed works, even though it's not a built-in property of DOM elements.